# Optimize search by hash in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

I have an InnoDB table with a lot of fields, one of them is a unique hash of 32 bytes (typical md5 result).

I have to do a lot of queries searching by that hash, but my table starts to be big (500.000 records), and this search takes a lot of time:

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE `key`='Bj8DzS7RmCG41nLdgOp0kEhNtrfPo3KF'
```

This took about 0.7s

I could create an index of this "hash" 32-bytes varchar column, but this table grows a lot and if I have to optimize table (to re-index), it takes a lot of time to do it (about 10 minutes in my case), locking all the other live queries.

So, what is the best way to optimize a query where you have to search by a 32-bytes varchar field ?

Comment: I don't get why you re-index. The problem seems to be here, indexing that column is the only reasonable answer.

Comment: Because each re-index took about 10 minutes !  and there's about 10.000 new rows each day ... so it would be nice to re-index each day (at 3am for example) ... but I don't want to LOCK the table for 10 minutes while re-indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an index, simple as that.

Also, you mention varchar but your column isn't variable length, so a char(32) would be more appropriate.

If you are concerned about the cost of maintaining the index as you insert new rows, you could look at partitioning the table into smaller chunks. For example, you could have 16 separate tables based on the first character of the hash, e.g. table_0, table_1....table_f - now each table only contains 30,000 records. Or you could partition on the first 2 chars to give 256 tables.

While you can do this manually, checkout [MySQL's built in support for partitioning too](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html).

Comment: Hi Paul ... char(32) is a nice tip ... on the other hand, the table partitioning will be again useless when I reach million records ... my concern is more about "re-indexing" when the index gets "old" by time ...

Comment: The index doesn't get old, you just get some performance advantages from rebuilding it. Note that using OPTIMIZE TABLE on InnoDB might not be the fastest way to do it - it might be more effective to drop and recreate the index - see http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/12/09/thinking-about-running-optimize-on-your-innodb-table-stop/

Note that partitioning still helps you as you would only be locking 1/16th (or 1/256th) of your rows at any one time.

Comment: Paul, it's ok ... but I don't want to lock tables in any case. I can not permit it. I will do some tests. thank you

Comment: InnoDB tables only have a write lock during index creation, so you're only locked from doing an insert. If these hashes are randomly assigned, you could avoid creating new hashes for a partition that has an index being recreated.

Comment: ...and of course another option is just to not bother recreating the index until you can have some scheduled downtime. You might find that is perfectly acceptable performance-wise.